# OneDrive Api for Windows Universal APP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, msdn, onedrive

I am trying to run sample one drive app, I have MSDN account but still when I try to Sign in It says not authorized.
Do I need any Paid Account to access onedrive for Universal App?

Sample is located at 
[OneDrive Universal App](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/tree/master/samples/OneDrivePhotoBrowser)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need paid account for sure. I am using [Live SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveSDK) to consume Onedrive API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your app with OneDrive to get a client ID? https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm

Answer (score 0):

After enough google searches amd articles I found that If one wants to use OneDrive Api in Windowss Universal app , one need to have paid account on Windows Store for application.
If you are satisfied with using REST api of Onedrive than you don't need registration.

[Link for app in SDK and Rest Api Tested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632271.aspx)